# Converting Text Files

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text file containing these. I will load it in created form.

```
5JB01141570J4450901            1000    1051    2000    01161501B10G610M0350M200  0000006
```

to produce this.

```
106262,5,JB,2015-01-14,70J4450901            ,1000    ,1051    ,2000    ,2015-01-16,0,1,B10G610M0350M200  ,6,, ,0,1/14/2015 3:06:16 PM
```

how can it converted to it?

the first column is the row counts and the last column indicates datetime when generated..

Comment: is the text fixed in size? you can strip by counting the index and put in array, and produce the result

Comment: @WindyHendwiananda Yes it is. I've been trying to load it in a `DataReader` cant seem to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe a crude way, but try and adjust to suit yours. You get the idea.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static string data1;
        private static int[] idx = new int[12] { 0, 1, 3, 9, 31, 39, 47, 55, 61, 62, 63, 81 };

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dataInput = "5JB01141570J4450901            1000    1051    2000    01161501B10G610M0350M200  0000006";

            Console.WriteLine("RESULT :");

            for (int i = 0; i < idx.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                int len = idx[i + 1] - idx[i];

                //format date
                if (i == 2 | i == 7)
                {
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dataInput.Substring(idx[i], len).Substring(0, 2) +
                        "/" + dataInput.Substring(idx[i], len).Substring(2, 2) +
                        "/" + dataInput.Substring(idx[i], len).Substring(4, 2));
                    data1 = data1 + dt.ToShortDateString() + ",";
                }
                else {
                    data1 = data1 + dataInput.Substring(idx[i], len) + ",";
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(data1 + DateTime.Now);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```